# Why my wsl ubuntu's default git branch is Master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Whenever I use wsl to make any project and try to add project on git it shows the master as a default branch. But when I use windows to create project it shows main. I want to change the default branch of wsl to main

I have tried chatgpt to solve the problem but it messed me up

Comment: The global config is probably different. Check `git config --global -l` on both environments and they will vary (particularly about the config of the default branch name).

Comment: Yes, both usernames are different. windows git says its main but wsl has no answer about branches. it only shows username and email

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default branch to be used by GIT with the following command

`git config --global init.defaultBranch master`

Use the same branch in both WSL and windows.

Additionally, you can also look at your current gitconfig settings using `cat ~/.gitconfig`

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
        name = Your Name
        email = your.name@mail.com
[init]
        defaultBranch = master
```

Comment: it's not showing the default branch

Comment: if i add the following command `git config --global init.defaultBranch master` then it shows master if I change master to main it also shows master.

Comment: Now the default branch is showing main (after typing `cat ~/.gitconfig`) but when I type `git branch` it shows master